# Generate post slug and route on Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, slug

I'm creating a blog post with Laravel 5.5. Here I want to auto-generate accessible slug for a post upon saving. What I did here was:

```
'slug' => str_slug(request('title'))
```

It generates the slug value but the page url is not working. For e.g if I click `127.0.0.1:8000/title` it should redirect me.

**Controller**

```
public function save(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $post= new Post;
    $post->title = request('title');
    $post->slig => str_slug(request('title'));

    $post->save();
}
```

**Route**

```
    Route::post('/', 'PostsController@save')->name('add_post');
```

Comment: where is the controller and the route for your find by slug?

Comment: Yes, I want to generate hyperlink for a page based on slug value stored on database. I only able store slug value to database.

Comment: you just do some concatenation

Comment: Did not get you. Concatenation where?

Comment: concatenate the slug to your url

Comment: where is the controller and the route for your find by slug?

Comment: Can you show us that segment of your route and controller that deals with your blog post?

Comment: Only this much information will not help you to get an answer. Please share your route and controller code as-well. Else this question will be flagged and closed.

Answer (score 1):

we store the title and replace every space to dash '-' to auto-generate accessible slug for a post upon saving on this steps :
i use this code on controller

```
   public function store(Request $request){$post->slug = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($post->title));}
```

and on

```
public function show($slug)
{
    //
    $post=Post::where('slug',$slug)->first();
    return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
}
```

and edit post link like this

```
<a href="/posts/{{$post->slug}}">link</a>
```

Comment: public function show($slug)
    {
        //
        $post=Post::where('slug',$slug)->first();
        return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
    }

Comment: Can you share some more context? And please don't add code in the comment section, just edit your answer

Comment: i add more explain @NicoHaase

Comment: And can you explain what exactly in your code solves the original problem? Such an answer could be of long-time value for other users searching for help

Comment: we store the title and replace every space to dash '-' to  auto-generate accessible slug for a post upon saving

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the answer, not to the comment section

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using one of the Sluggable packages. https://packagist.org/?q=sluggable I have used the one by Spatie before and it works well.

Once you create your new entity/model and you then have a slug you will need to create a route to a controller which looks up the entity using the slug field.

```
$thing = Thing::whereSlug($request->get('slug'))->firstOrFail();
```